# How can set Windows Explorer startup path with python

Tags: python, windows-explorer

I want to set Windows Explorer startup path with python.

like this. %windir%\explorer.exe C:\Users.This is a global setting.

it’s need pywin32 or cmd or regedit?

please help me。
thanks

Comment: You can launch explorer to a startup path as a one-off thing with `explorer.exe /root,c:\users` ( see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853 ) ... but what do you mean "set the startup path" and "this is a global setting" and "does it need regedit"? Can you give examples of what you want? e.g. "person clicks {here}, Explorer shows {something}" ?

Comment: hi masters, I want to set its default path. like this:http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-explorer-defaults-libraries-folder-windows-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link in your comment looks to be modifying a `.lnk` shortcut file's target property.

Python with PyWin32:

- [Reading the target of a .lnk file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397125/478656)
- [Modify Windows unicode shortcuts using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916069/modify-windows-unicode-shortcuts-using-python)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6806426/478656

or PowerShell:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/534409/478656

The default explorer link might be in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\`