# <unknown>.TargetPath can not be set

Tags: python-2.7, win32com, comtypes

I'm attempting to write a script that can be deployed and remotely run on a number of target computers with the end result of having an existing shortcut replaced by one that runs the exact same program, but at high priority. Here is my script:

```
import os, winshell
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
# from comtypes.gen import IWshRuntimeLibrary

desktop = winshell.desktop()
path = os.path.join(desktop, 'Test Short.lnk')

target = r'\%HOMEDRIVE%\\Apps\\Ellie Mae\\Encompass\\AppLauncher.exe'
wDir = r'\%HOMEDRIVE%\\Apps\\Ellie Mae\\Encompass'
icon = r'\%SystemRoot%\\Installer\\{3E9C4FBE-4E6C-4389-A4B3-4AE027D0BF2E}\\Icon3E9C4FBE2.ico'

shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.TargetPath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

I'm running into an Attribute error, as follows:

```
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.TargetPath' can not be set.
```

For reference, [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/23/using-python-to-create-shortcuts/) is where I got most of my code.

I attempted to search out an answer, and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805881/modify-windows-shortcuts-using-python) thread. However, following the accepted suggestion yields:

```
ImportError: cannot import name IWshRuntimeLibrary
```

My confusion comes from why I'm not able to set the TargetPath property to begin with. As happens so often, it seems as if the OP from the linked thread and I are the only two people reporting this problem. Does anyone know why that might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I have encountered the same problem.