# Python os.path.realpath() for symlink in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

It seems like realpath() does not resolve symlink (not shortcut - *.lnk) in Windows. I found an open bug for python3 here: https://bugs.python.org/issue9949

Is there any workaround? I'm mostly interested in Python 2.

Comment: Looks like the recommended approach is to delegate to Windows Shell, see [Reading the target of a .lnk file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python) and maybe click through the links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6805881/699305).

Comment: This answer is about shortcuts (*.lnk files). But I'm looking for reading actual Windows symlinks. Windows command: `mklink`

Comment: I'm using Python 2

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize they're two different things...

Comment: @alexis No problem. It is easy to be confused. It is actually hard links which Microsoft calls symlink - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx. Or backward? I'm confused too.

Comment: Your best bet might be to look at one of the [patches](https://bugs.python.org/review/9949/patch/13878/51626) submitted for that bug (along with the context in the bug tracker) and see if you can pull that code into your own project. (Be aware of licensing issues.)

Comment: Well a hard link in the Unix sense is indistinguishable from the original filename, so it wouldn't need any extra work to handle. God knows what Microsoft means by it, though.

Comment: @alexis, it means the same thing. A hardlink is another name for a file in a volume, but only a file since NTFS doesn't support directory hardlinks. The Windows API has `CreateHardlink` to make a link, and `FindFirstFileNameW` and `FindNextFileNameW` to list them for a given file.

Comment: How much of that patch do you need? If you just want to resolve a link whose target exists and is accessible to the current user, then you can use ctypes to call `CreateFile` and `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`, without too much effort.

Comment: @eryksun Unix doesn't _allow_ hard links to directories either; otherwise the directory structure would no longer be a tree, which would create serious traversal problems.

Comment: @alexis, Unix filesystems support it in principle. The "." and ".." entries are hardlinks. Some Unix systems have allowed root to create hardlinks to directories, and apparently OS X uses it for its "Time Machine". In NTFS there are no directory hard links at all, and "." and ".." don't exist on disk; they're faked in the directory listing.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that root could do it; but I didn't know the situation on NTFS, thanks. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4):

The Python function [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) returns the canonical path of the given path, eliminating simlinks.

On Windows 7, this function [does not work as expected](https://bugs.python.org/issue9949) as it fails to follow symbolic links (created with [mklink](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx). Since the bug has been opened for more than 7 years, I started looking for a workaround.

The solution I found was to replace

```
realpath = os.path.realpath(path)
```

by

```
realpath = path if not os.path.islink(path) else os.readlink(path)
```

Function [`os.readlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) does work correctly on Windows 7.

Comment: The workaround is not quite the same, because it will only follow a symlink for the full path - e.g. if `/foo` is a symlink to `/bar`, `realpath('/foo/qux')` would give you `'/bar/qux'` (where it works). It works well enough for many use cases, though.

Comment: `os.readlink()` was [fixed in python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue29248#msg312082).

Answer (score 1):

The [jaraco.windows project](https://pypi.org/project/jaraco.windows) supplies `jaraco.windows.filesystem.get_final_path` which may be what you're looking for. With the 3.9 release, it also has a `jaraco.windows.filesystem.backports` module, which presents the `realpath` function as proposed for that Python bug. Please give one or both of those functions a try and report back how it works.

If the `realpath` function works well for you, there is a `patch_os_module`, which as its name suggests, can patch the `os` module such that `os.path.realpath` has the behavior from the backport. At the time of this writing, it doesn't do that, but if that would be useful for your use-case, I'd be happy to add it.

Feel free to contribute to the project in Github. And please excuse the docs - they don't build properly on a Unix system such as RTD.